# Maven-Surefire-Plugin + systemPropertyVariables + Resource File = java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a resource file located in folder `src/test/java/resources/framework.properties` with this content:

```
felix.auto.start.1=\
"file:${test.archive.directory}/agenda.test-1.0.0.jar"
```

And I use (or pretend to use) the `maven-surefire-plugin` to replace that variable (`${test.archive.directory}`) by the correct value see sample ballow:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <test.archive.directory>${project.build.directory}</test.archive.directory>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It just fails miserably and the test returns this message error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${test.archive.directory}\testbundle.test-1.0.0.jar (The system cannot find the path specified))
```

Obviously the `maven-surefire-plugin` is not replacing the property value. I was digging all over internet and cannot find a decent answer to this, any idea of what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Consider also that I am running this code for an *Arquillian OSGi* test case. The parameters to replace above is for the *Arquillian* to locate the necessary bundles to run the tests so the replacement of the parameter must be made before the framework starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<test.archive.directory>${project.build.directory}</test.archive.directory>
```

is available as System property to the Java process it spans off for surefire, you can read them by

```
System.getProperty("test.archive.directory");
```

in your Java class, you can't expect it to magically replace it in properties file

Comment: The call to `System.getProperty("test.archive.directory")` returns `null`. Any idea why? There are about 100+ properties in `System.getProperties()` but none of them come from the `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Comment: try via `http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html` Special VM Properties may be